# How to setup Flowbite with Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nfn4y3?file=/nuxt.config.js) with Nuxt and Flowbite.

Imported according to instructions from Flowbite

The problem is that the styles of the flowbite components are displayed correctly, but the dynamic components do not work.

What could be the problem?

Perhaps this is due to the fact that the nuxt application is selected to render as static, because with SSR rendering dynamic components work, but this is not suitable for me, I need an application without SSR.

Comment: You're using `ssr: false`, so this is an SPA. Setting `target: 'server'` have no real sense tbh because it will be a single entry point anyway (since it's an SPA). I'll maybe try to debug this one later on. What is not working exactly? Could you highlight this part? Like the modal?

Comment: @kissu All dynamic elements do not work in the sandbox (modal, close alert, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

Achieved to make it work with Nuxt3 thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite/issues/131#issuecomment-1100830582), here's a working [Github repo](https://github.com/kissu/n3-configure-flowbite).

---

#### Old answer

I've spent more time working on this subject recently. Check my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71835433/8816585) for more details.

TLDR: Nuxt2 and 3 are not supported regarding the components requiring some JS (modals, dropdown etc...).