# How to add Flowbite Tailwind plugin to my Laravel 9 + Vite project?

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, vite, laravel-9, flowbite

I tried adding flowbite to my Laravel project. I am using Laravel version 9 with Vite.

So far, I did the following steps:

1. Installed `flowbite` as a dependency:

```bash
npm i flowbite
```

2. Added plugin in `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
plugins: [
  require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
  require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
  require('flowbite/plugin')
],
```

3. I imported it in `App.js`:

````js
import Flowbite from 'flowbite';


4. Then I ran the app:
```shell
npm run dev
````

I also tried adding it using CDN links, but it's not working.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Or maybe you can suggest me a better library to use with Tailwind CSS, as Tailwind doesn't provide js components like tooltip, dropdown, etc.

```
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .mixin({ components: { FilePond } })
            .mount(el);
    },
});
```

Comment: Keep your question properly formatted rather than rollback'ing it to a previous state, your question is self-answered anyway so I don't really see the benefit of making the question look worse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution for this issue. In the Main `App.vue` file, I imported `initFlowbite` from `'flowbite'` and called it within the `onMounted` lifecycle hook like this:

In the Main `App.vue`

```js
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite';
    
onMounted(() => {
  initFlowbite();
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For me worked to add this line of code in to the app.js

```
import 'flowbite';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you want some logic: https://headlessui.com/

Regarding a Flowbite + Nuxt setup, here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71835459/8816585

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solutions but you can give it a try to install Flowbite without any settings:

1. put the css and js files inside ./public/js/flowbite.js & ./public/css/flowbite.min.css
2. put the code below in your blade templates

```html
<link href="{{ url('css/flowbite.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="{{ url('js/flowbite.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer based on https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/laravel/

For what I do, if you add it to app.js, you can fully import into your app.js using this syntax

```js
import "../../path/to/node_modules/flowbite/dist/flowbite"; // @see https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/laravel/
```

Then on your vite, import the app.js normally, as you do

```php
<script src="{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Vite::asset('resources/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

That will work as it's, for tooltips, etc, see on each docs like https://flowbite.com/docs/components/tooltips/