# Flowbite is not working with inertia Laravel App

Tags: tailwind-css, inertiajs, laravel-10, flowbite

I am currently using Laravel version 10 along with Vite, Tailwind, and Inertia.js for my project. Previously, when I was not using Inertia.js, I was able to install and use Flowbite in my project by using the command "npm install flowbite" and importing it with the statement "import 'flowbite';" in my app.js file. However, I have encountered an issue where Flowbite is not working anymore since I started using Inertia.js in Laravel.

Could you please assist me in resolving this issue?

Here is my App.js code:

```
`import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';
import 'flowbite';
const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

`
even its not working if i try to add cdn links in app.blade.php

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title inertia>{{ config('app.name', 'Bathinda Chemicals') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
        <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"/>
        <!-- Scripts -->
        @routes
        @vite('resources/js/app.js')

        @inertiaHead
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.4.5/dist/flowbite.min.css" />

    </head>
    {{-- <body class="font-sans antialiased">

    </body> --}}
    <body class="m-0 font-sans antialiased font-normal dark:bg-slate-900 text-base leading-default bg-gray-50 text-slate-500">

        <div class="absolute w-full bg-indigo-500 dark:hidden h-80"></div>
        <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
            @inertia
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.4.5/dist/flowbite.js"></script>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`

I tried Adding This code too..

```
`module.exports = {
    content: [
      "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
      "./resources/**/*.js",
      "./resources/**/*.vue",
      "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"
    ],
    theme: {
      extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [
        require('flowbite/plugin')
    ],
  }`
```

Comment: Just to clarify, for this project you are using just base Vue 3, right? And not something like Laravel Splade?

Comment: yes! base Vue 3

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Just posted an answer to what I believe the issue is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across this issue before and in my case, I had to initialize Flowbite in the Vue file with one of the lifecycle methods.

Try this in your Vue file:

```cpp
<script>
import { initFlowbite } from "flowbite";

export default {

    mounted() {
        initFlowbite(); // Initialize Flowbite on mount of the Vue component
    },
}
</script>
```

With this, all of the Flowbite components will be you use will be initialized. In my case, I used Popovers and it didn't work until I used the `initFlowbite()` function.

You can read more about it [here](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/quickstart/#init-functions).

Also, the above example I provided was with Vue's Options API. If you're using the Composition API it can be done like this:

```cpp
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite'

// initialize components based on data attribute selectors
onMounted(() => {
    initFlowbite();
})
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76061309/9076175

Comment: Thank you!  i also got it working with same solution. Thank you dear!

Comment: Happy to help! Do accept the answer as the solution if possible, please. It would be my first on StackOverflow :D

Answer (score 1):

I've a Laravel 10 with Vue3/InertiaJs using Vite and typescript. I tried `initFlowbite()` on `onMounted` (composition API) hook almost everywhere and it didn't work. The only thing that works in my project is to use inertia events (https://inertiajs.com/events) on my `app.ts` file

```js
import { router } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite';

router.on('success', (event) => {
  initFlowbite()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As an improvement for @marcobaro response, as I can't add a comment.

For me, it didn't work exactly that way, I had to add another `initFlowbite()` in the `createInertiaApp` block, because flowbite didn't load on the first page load, I had to go to another route and then go back to a route that using something that's related to flowbite js. So, here's how it worked for me (btw I'm using Laravel 10 with Vue 3, with JavaScript not TypeScript):

In `app.js` or `boostrap.js`, or in the file that has `createInertiaApp(...)`, this is the original `createInertiaApp` that It got generated with Laravel Breeze:

```js
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

All I did was:

```js
.then(() => {
    initFlowbite();
});
```

This will initiate and load flowbite on the page refresh, at first, I add it like this, but when I navigated to another route and got back to the route that has some flowbite.js-related code, it didn't load correctly, so thanks to  @marcobaro , it worked after navigating to another route, but when I removed my code block `.then(...)` it didn't work on the first page load, so I had to add both. So, the entire code should be:

```js
import '../css/app.css';
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import {createInertiaApp, router} from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy';
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite';

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
}).then(() => {
    // on first load
    initFlowbite();
});

router.on('success', (event) => {
    // on each router load, this fixes the issue that flowbite has with inertia.
    initFlowbite();
});
```

I hope this will work for anyone facing this problem, and I wish if there's a better way we can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

We've just released new integration docs for `flowbite-react` including `Laravel + Inertia`, u can find it here:

https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/guides/laravel

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35449585)